# KeyboardDateTimePicker from '@material-ui/pickers' is becoming unresponsive as soon as the track is dragged to change time. How to stop this?

Tags: reactjs, user-interface, material-ui, draggable, datetimepicker

**Here is the code for the picker I used,what could be the reason for this behavior? Is there a possible way to stop draggable feature in the MUI time picker?**

```
    <KeyboardDateTimePicker
          autoOk
          id={date.id}
          inputVariant="outlined"
          variant="inline"
          margin="normal"
          label={date.label}
          maxDate={findId(date.type) ? todate : date.maxDate}
          minDate={!findId(date.type) ? fromdate : date.minDate}
          format="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a"
          size={props.size ? props.size : "medium"}
          value={todate}
          disabled={date.disabled ? props.disabled : false}
          onChange={ (event) => storeDate(date.id,event) }
          keyboardIcon={<icons.DateRangeIcon style={{color: colours.green}} fontSize="small"/>}
          dateRangeIcon={<icons.DateRangeIcon style={{color: colours.white}} fontSize="medium"/>}
          timeIcon={<icons.AccessTimeIcon style={{color: colours.white}} fontSize="medium" />}
          style={{minWidth: "100%"}}
          InputLabelProps={{
            style: {fontSize:13}
          }}
        />
```